# 1x1 Convolution learnable parameters

Tags: convolution

Here is a code snippet wherein I add two convolution layers one with 3x3 filter followed by a layer with 1x1 filter. While I am sure how the parameters are calculated for 3x3 filter, I could not figure out the learnable parameter calculation for 1x1 convolution. Could someone help me understand?

```
model = Sequential()
inputShape = (227, 227, 3)
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
 input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1,1)))
```

Upon running `model.summary()`, the output is like:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 227, 227, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 227, 227, 32)      1056      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,952
Trainable params: 1,952
Non-trainable params: 0
```

How did it arrive at 1056 parameters for the 1x1 convolution?

Comment: The number of parameters is a sum of the number of weights (`n_channels_in x n_channels_out = 32 x 32 = 1024`) and the number of biases (`n_channels_out = 32`), which adds up to `1056`.

Comment: @Oxbowerce mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters in a convolutional layer can be calculated using the following formula: `(filter_width * filter_height * n_filters_in) + 1) * n_filters_out`. Filling in the numbers for your example we get `((1 * 1 * 32) + 1) * 32 = 33 * 32 = 1056`, which aligns with the number you get from `model.summary()`. Of these `1056` parameters, `1024 (1 * 1 * 32 * 32)` are the layer weights, the other `32 (1 * 32)` are for the layer biases.